# What is the simplest way I can check to see if an array has elements or not?

Tags: javascript

How can I determine if an array has elements and return false if that array is not defined?

I have the array `modal.questions`

I was using modal.questions.length but now this seems to be a problem if questions is not defined.

Is there a way I can do this using a libray function of _underscore.js or a simple way I can code a function to make the check?

Comment: @Felix King It is similar but not an exact duplicate  The alleged duplicate question considers a zero length array to be valid.  The current question does not. Detecting zero length arrays requires more esoteric Javascript like instanceOf

Comment: @Melina -- Or actualy, your question might be vague.  Did you know you can have perfectly good defined array, that is empty, like `A=[];` .  Do you want `true` or `false`  with that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function isEmpty(theArray) {
    return theArray == null || theArray.length <= 0;
}
```

Comment: this does not work if i pass a null

Answer (score 1):

`if(modal.questions && modal.questions.length > 0) {}`

should work.

Answer (score 0):

check `if(modal.questions === undefined)` first, then do your length check.

Note: in some older browsers it was possible to overwrite value of `undefined`. In such case a safe check would be `if(modal.questions === void 0)` as `void 0` will return actual `undefined` value. If however you're targetting modern browsers, you need not worry about that.

Comment: If array is null, or for some reason it is not an array, then checking length may throw an error.

Answer (score 0):

try like this:

```
if (typeof array !== 'undefined' && array.length > 0) {
    // existss and have one item
}
```

Comment: When `array = null` it throws `TypeError Cannot read property 'length' of null`

Answer (score 0):

This works in all the browsers

```
if(!Array.isArray) {
  Array.isArray = function (vArg) {
    return Object.prototype.toString.call(vArg) === "[object Array]";
  };
}

//add length check also here
function isEmpty(theArray) {
    return Array.isArray(theArray)    
}

var a = new Array();
var b = null;
var c = undefined;
var d = [];

alert(isEmpty(a)); //true
alert(isEmpty(b)); //false
alert(isEmpty(c)); //false
alert(isEmpty(d)); //true
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GZZ2n/)

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/isArray) :)